# Update element with AJAX, but without animation

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces `ckEditor`. Want to disable the 'Save' button untill user not type something in this ckEditor component. I can reach this by using `<p:ajax event="change/>`, but then update animation appears on every typed letter. How can I reach this in jsf/primefaces without these animation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an Ajax request is triggered for each keystroke, your application will not be very efficient. First of all, add a `delay="..."` to your `p:ajax` listener to reduce the number of calls:

> If less than delay milliseconds elapses between calls to `request()` only the most recent one is sent and all other requests are discarded. The default value of this option is `null`. If the value of delay is the literal string 'none' without the quotes or the default, no delay is used.

Regarding the Ajax status animation (I guess you are talking about), add `global="false"` to your `p:ajax` listener:

> Global ajax requests are listened by `ajaxStatus` component, setting global to `false` will not trigger `ajaxStatus`.

Comment: thank you so much! Setting 'global' to 'false' is working ideally for me!